# Joomla 3.4.1 error message 'Table 'joomla3.o6fqu_updates' doesn't exist'

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla3.4

When I try and install new extensions I receive error:

> 'Table 'joomla3.o6fqu_updates' doesn't exist SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS
>   FROM 'o6fqu_updates'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Seem that this table is missing from your installation.
You have to run this query via phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `o6fqu_updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

Above query copied from 3.4.1 installation file. Not sure if it has compatibility with previous versions. I have added `o6fqu` table prefix that is used to your `joomla3` database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am new to Joomla where exactly do I add this code?